# How to find which vertex has out-degree equal to v-1 in a simple DAG with only adjacency matrix in O(V)?

Tags: algorithm, graph, adjacency-matrix, vertex

I have a **simple directed graph**, with **no anti-parallel edges**. I need to find an algorithm to determine if this graph contains a vertex with **out-deg=|V|-1 and in-deg=0**.

The input of this algorithm can only be an **adjacency-matrix** of this graph. And using this adjacency-matrix, we need to do it in **O(|V|)**.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Since there can be at most one such node, this can be done by iteratively eliminating candidates.

First, put all nodes onto a stack. We will use this stack to keep our candidates.

As long as we have at least two nodes `p` and `q` on the stack, check if the edge `(p, q)` exists. If it exists, then `q` cannot have in-degree 0 and we can remove it from the stack. If it does not exist, then `p` cannot have out-degree `|V|-1`, so we can remove it from the stack. Hence, after each check, we remove exactly one candidate, which allows us to arrive at a single candidate after `O(|V|)` checks.

Now we only need to check this node for the given in- and out-degree by checking the corresponding row and column in the adjacency matrix, which can also be done in `O(|V|)`.

Comment: Hey, thank you Nico for your answer. What do you mean for "put all nodes onto a stack" ? Because we don't have the nodes, we only have an adjacency-matrix (V^2 matrix)

Comment: Then put the index of the node onto the stack.